# MySql .NET membership provider rejects logins since upgrade

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, mysql-connector

I recently upgraded MySql Connector /NET 6.0.4.0 to version 6.4.4.0. My site uses the MySql Membership Provider to process logins, but since upgrading no users can log in. That is to say, `Membership.ValidateUser(user, password)` returns false for previously valid usernames and passwords.

I'm conscious that I haven't specified an encryption/hashing key anywhere in web.config, and maybe the new version hashes passwords differently by default? If I create a new user, they can log in just fine, it's just all the old users who can no longer log in.

Is there a workaround to save hundreds of people from having to set new passwords? Or at least to stop a repeat of this problem if I upgrade again in the future?

**web.config**

```
<system.web>
  <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieTimeout="240" createPersistentCookie="true" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
    <providers>
       <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" autogenerateschema="true" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/"/>
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
  ...
</system.web>
```

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 and connecting to MySql 5.

**EDIT** This just got wierder; it seems that some users can still log in, but others can't. My old login definitely stopped working, and I've checked that it's not locked out or anything.